# Table of Content for Microsoft.interop.word.dll

Tags: c#, .net, interop

I have created table of content for my word document generated by C# application and it works fine

```
Range myRange = aDoc.Range(ref missing, ref missing);
object oStyleName = "Heading 1";
myRange.set_Style(ref oStyleName);
object start = wordApp.ActiveDocument.Content.End - 1;
Range rangeForTOC = aDoc.Range(ref start, ref missing);
TableOfContents toc = aDoc.TablesOfContents.Add(rangeForTOC, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
toc.Update();
Range rngTOC = toc.Range;
rngTOC.Font.Size = 10;
rngTOC.Font.Name = "Georgia";
```

but the issue is it will not navigate to that particular section when i click on the content .. can anyone help me regarding this issue

Answer (score 0):

Please find below updated code:

```
Range myRange = aDoc.Range(ref missing, ref missing);
object oStyleName = "Heading 1";
object oTrueValue = true;
myRange.set_Style(ref oStyleName);
object start = wordApp.ActiveDocument.Content.End - 1;
Range rangeForTOC = aDoc.Range(ref start, ref missing);
TableOfContents toc = aDoc.TablesOfContents.Add(rangeForTOC,
    ref oTrueValue, ref missing, ref missing,
    ref missing, ref missing, ref oTrueValue, 
    ref oTrueValue, ref oTrueValue, ref oTrueValue,
    ref oTrueValue, ref oTrueValue);
toc.Update();

Range rngTOC = toc.Range;
rngTOC.Font.Size = 10;
rngTOC.Font.Name = "Georgia";
```

You need to include true value object (varTrueValue) and use it while creating TableOfContents.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: If you are referring to the `UseHyperlinks` parameter of the [`TablesOfContents.Add(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.tablesofcontents.add(v=office.14).aspx) method, according to the documentation, it will only have an effect when publishing to the web. Additionally, the default for this parameter is true so it is not necessary to set it to true explicitly. If navigation does not appear to be working for your table of contents, be sure that you are holding down the Ctrl key when you click and not just merely clicking.